# Make static cell in tableviewcontroller bring up composed mail when pressed

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, static-content

[image]

I would like to make the "Leave a Suggestion" static cell open the mail and allow me to compose a message with a set subject. How would I accomplish this?

**EDIT:**

```
import UIKit
import MessageUI

class AccountViewController: UITableViewController, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate {

        @IBOutlet var Logout: UILabel!

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()


        @IBAction func emailButtonAction(_ sender: UIButton) {

            if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() {
                let mail = MFMailComposeViewController()
                mail.mailComposeDelegate = self
                mail.setToRecipients(["example@gmail.com"])
                mail.setSubject("Example Subject")
                mail.setMessageBody("<p>Test</p>", isHTML: true)
                present(mail, animated: true)
            }
        }

        func mailComposeController(_ controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWith result: MFMailComposeResult, error: Error?) {
            controller.dismiss(animated: true)
        }
    }
```

UIButton does not work with any of my cells

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the requester has not shown any effort to solve the problem.

Comment: I've tried changing the label's to buttons and importing the message UI into the view controller swift file but nothing seems to be working

Comment: Can you show the code that you have been using so far? It's hard to tell what you're doing wrong without seeing what it is that you are doing

Comment: Sorry about that, edited it in

Comment: Why don't you use tableviewDidSelect delegate method ?? Instead of UIbutton ?

Comment: I'm a beginner in swift and still trying to learn all the actions, I will look into that delegate some more, thank you

Comment: Kindly use didSelectRow method for this instead of label, just outside other functions and inside the class body, type 'didSelectRow', xcode will show suggestions, select the one with 'didSelectRowAt IndexPath', this function will be called every time you select a row in that specific table. To determine which row is selected you can use indexPath.row which is most appropriate way. if you are a beginner my suggestion would be that you start with learning basics of the table views before going to advance apps.

Comment: @AshishSharma He is using static table view cells, those delegate methods don't apply.

Comment: If you connected your @IBAction to your storyboard button, your function should be called. Try adding `print("button touched!")` to the top of your function to see it is getting called. My guess is `MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail()` is returning false. Are you running on device or simulator?

Comment: I'm not sure where to connect the @IBAction to my storyboard because the static view cells don't work like buttons